# Houseplants not looking good

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations

I recently moved and now my money tree and monstera are getting brown / yellow leaves and leaf drop. I think the monstera is too far gone but any help would be appreciated!!! I had to walk them outside for a few minutes in single digit weather. My thought is humidity? I’m planning on buying a humidifier tomorrow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide images of the plants so we can assess them properly.

Comment: Thank you! Just added a link :)

Comment: How much have you been watering them? Check it's roots, if they look unhealthy it's a sign of rot. Revert then (possibly with pics ).

Comment: A few minutes of cold does not kill a plant.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like damage due to low temperatures.  The diagnosis is based on:

- no sign of pests
- damage is all over

I recommend doing nothing for the net few week.  Put them as close to more light as possible in an area with no cold drafts and go easy on the water.

It's likely that after a few weeks the damaged leaves will go dry and crispy and can be removed.  Or, if you favor the tough love approach, just remove all the damaged leaves now.  They are not going to get better so might as well remove them and force some new growth.